# iOS Audio not continuing playback in background or lockscreen

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

After running `eas build --profile preview --platform ios` and installing on my iPhone 12 Mini, the audio doesn't continue playing when I close the app or lock the screen.

I have set the following in my app.json as per the [Expo Audio docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/).

After installing the build on my device, I expect the music to continue playback as I leave the app or activate the lockscreen. The audio seems to pause immediately, but instantly resume when I reopen the app.

```
"ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.rahlok.pplay",
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIBackgroundModes": [
          "audio"
        ]
      }
    },
```

Here is my Player.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

export default function Player() {
  const [sound, setSound] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      staysActiveInBackground: true,
    });
  })

  async function playSound() {
    console.log('Loading Sound');
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync( require('../assets/demo.mp3')
    );
    setSound(sound);

    console.log('Playing Sound');
    await sound.playAsync();
  }

  async function pauseSound() {

    console.log('Pausing Sound');
    await sound.pauseAsync();
  }

  async function resumeSound() {
    console.log('Resuming Sound');
    await sound.playAsync();
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log('Unloading Sound');
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Play Sound" onPress={playSound} />
      <Button title="Pause Sound" onPress={pauseSound} />
      <Button title="Resume Sound" onPress={resumeSound} />
    </View>
  );
}
```